# url not opened on iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Am trying to open a url ontouch of an overlay .
the overlay is on top of the iframe (which houses the url)

```
 var initiatelandingpage = function(){
        document.getElementById('overlay4527').style.display = 'none';
       setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('overlay4527').style.display = 'block';
     },500);
 };
```

ontouchstart event , i hid the overlay and display it in 500ms which fires the url properly on ios device

Above same when i try to do with ontouchend event, somehow the  url is not opening on ios device

Am clueless as why this is happening and want a fix for the same.

[jsfiddle for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/x2wp52k1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version of IOS you are using, later version don't support iframe anymore, AFAIK

Comment: @Nyfer : is the url https protected ??

Comment: If this is the url : http://m.nike.com/in/en_gb/c/running/ then either it has  to be https or make changes in your info.plist file

Comment: @TerrilThomas , thanks . but its not app . its just an html ad which am try to run on iphone browser (safari/chrome)